# Clear firefox cache quicker

Tags: firefox

I make changes to my JS then I clear out my cache by doing CMD + shift + back space (on mac) and then select I want to clear out my cache and leave cookies etc alone.

I was wondering is there an even faster way to clear out my cache.

Any firefox plugin which does it in one click or one button?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Ctrl F5: Refresh the page by clearing the cache. Reloads all images, css, js and swf

Comment: Issue is not refreshing. It's clearing.  Want to do it in one click not two.